# Django - how can I get permalink to work with "throwaway" slug

Tags: python, django, django-urls, permalinks

I'm trying to add slugs to the url in my django app, much like SO does.

Currently, I have pages that work just fine with a url like this:

```
http://example.com/foo/123/
```

I'd like to add 'slugified' urls like so:

```
http://example.com/foo/123/foo-name-here
```

I can get it to work just fine, by simply modifying the urlconf and adding a throwaway value to the view function:

```
#urls.py

ulpatterns = patterns('project.app.views',
    url(r'^foo/(?P<foo_id>\d+)/(?P<name_slug>\w+)/$', 'foo_detail', name='foo_detail'),
)

#views.py:

def foo_detail(request, foo_id, name_slug):
    # stuff here, name slug is just discarded
```

Visting the url with the slug works just fine.

However, my problem is when I am using `@models.permalink`.

For my `Foo` model, I used to have the following, which worked just fine:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('foo_detail', [str(self.id),])
```

However, after my change, whenever I call `{{ foo.get_absolute_url }}` in my templates, the result is always an empty string.

I have tried the following two replacements for `get_absolute_url`, neither of which is working:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# attempt 1
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('foo_detail', [str(self.id), slugify(self.name)])

# attempt 2
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('foo_detail', (), {
        'foo_id': str(self.id), 
        'name_slug': slugify(self.name),
    })
```

Note that if I add a `print slugify(self.name)` before returning, the slugified name is showing up in the console just fine.

When invoking `{{ foo.get_absolute_url }}` in my templates, the result is always an empty string, and I don't get any errors.

I know I could replace the method with `return '/foo/%s/%s' % (str(self.id), slugify(self.name))`, but I'm trying to get the permalink working so that my URL is only defined in one place.   What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I should note that the way I was doing this is kind've weird and unnecessary:  there's no reason I needed to keep `name_slug` in the urlconf or the view function.   After the answerer pointed out my problem i was able to go back to `r'^foo/(?P<foo_id>\d+)/([\w-]+)/$'` and `foo_detail(request, foo_id):`  respectively, which is cleaner.

Comment: which permalink method did you end up using ?  I am looking at the same thing ...

Comment: @thornomad attempt #1 in my question was what I ended up with.  turns out there was no problem with the `get_absolute_url` methods I had, just with my url pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing to check for, because I also ran into this problem:

```
(?P<name_slug>\w+)
```

Is slugify adding hyphens anywhere?  If so the regex won't match, hypens are a non-word character.  To fix use `[\w-]+` or similar.