# How do I perform a view lookup with a pk and subsequently redirect to a url with the correct slug? (django)

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, response.redirect

I'm trying to configure my app's routing such that the appropriate view page is looked up via the pk, and it returns a redirect with the proper url that has the correct slug following.

For example, I have the model `Post` with the `title` and `slug` fields. Let's say I have a `Post` object with the pk `1` and slug `hello-world`. What I would like to happen is that you will be redirected to `/post/1/hello-world/`, whether I navigate to:

- `/post/1/`
- `/post/1/hello-world/`, or
- `/post/1/wrong-slug/`

The reason why I would like to do this is so that if I happen to update this post's slug to, say, `hello-world-revised`, going to `/post/1/hello-world/` will (a) still return the correct view, and (b) redirect to the updated/correct url (aka `/post/1/hello-world-revised/`).

I have this in my app's `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<post_id>\d+)(?:/(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+))?/$', views.post, name='blog-post'),
)
```

And in `views.py`:

```
def post(request, post_id, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    return render(request, 'blog/post.html', {'post': post})
```

This gets me (a) above (retrieving the correct view), but not (b). To try and achieve (b), I have tried:

- Performing a redirect in my post view:

  ```
  def post(request, post_id, slug):
      post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
      return redirect('blog-post', post.id, post.slug)
  ```

  But when I navigate to any post, I get the "This webpage has a redirect loop" error.
- Overriding the `get_absolute_url` method on my `Post` model (following the pattern described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569837/django-how-can-i-get-permalink-to-work-with-throwaway-slug)):

  ```
  class Post(models.Model):
      ...

      @models.permalink
      def get_absolute_url(self):
          kwargs = {
              'post_id': str(self.id),
              'slug': self.slug,
          )
          return ('blog-post', (), kwargs)
  ```

  But that didn't have any effect; the correct view returned, but the URL remained as whatever you had typed in initially.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a condition in your redirect:

```
def post(request, post_id, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    if slug != post.slug
        return redirect('blog-post', post.id, post.slug)
    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/post.html', {'post': post})
```

Comment: Ugh, yes. Long day was long. Thanks :)